# How get the total revenue of a product

Tags: reports, statistics

I am trying to get a report about the total sales for a specific product.

More specific, I get the total sold items for this product but I want to get the total revenue too. However, I observe that the final price of product could be change because sometimes the product has been sold with sale price.

How can I get the total revenue of a product based on completed orders? 
or how can I get the average price which has been sold a product?

Answer (score 0):

you can see with MySQL query

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user_name";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "db_name";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT SUM((IFNULL(main_table.base_total_invoiced, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_tax_invoiced, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_shipping_invoiced, 0) - (IFNULL(main_table.base_total_refunded, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_tax_refunded, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_shipping_refunded, 0))) * main_table.base_to_global_rate) AS `lifetime`, AVG((IFNULL(main_table.base_total_invoiced, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_tax_invoiced, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_shipping_invoiced, 0) - (IFNULL(main_table.base_total_refunded, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_tax_refunded, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_shipping_refunded, 0))) * main_table.base_to_global_rate) AS `average` FROM `sales_order` AS `main_table` WHERE ( main_table.status NOT IN ( 'canceled' ) ) AND ( main_table.state NOT IN ( 'new', 'pending_payment' ) ) limit 0,1";
?>
<div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
     <table class="table table-hover">
          <tr>
              <th> total sale</th>
              <th>
average sale</th>

     </tr>
<tr>
<?php
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
<td><?php echo $row['lifetime'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['average'];?></td>
       <?php
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?> 
</tr>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```